# Taking Form Input Tag as Array

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to get Input form values in array and named all the input(text) tags as Val[] am getting it after Isset submition but it is just echoing only the first letter of each Input Value
Html.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="val[]" value="">
            <input type="text" name="val[]" value="">
            <input type="text" name="val[]" value="">
            <input type="text" name="val[]" value="">
            <input type="text" name="val[]" value="">
            <input type="text" name="val[]" value="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $varb = $_POST['val'];
                foreach($varb as $vals){
                echo $vals['val'];
                }
}
```

i actually don't know how to handle Array through Input fields

Comment: echo $vals instead of $vals['val'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see what you have in `$_POST['val']` using `var_dump($_POST['val'])` and use if u don't know what in array. For your example you should use just `... echo $vals; ...`

Answer (score 0):

What you actually get in PHP with your HTML form markup is an array like

```
array(
    [0] => first value
    [1] => second value
)
```

So you can access an array element of it like this

```
$array = $_POST['val'];
echo $array[0]; // Value of first input field
```

Or if you like to iterate over all the entries:

```
$array = $_POST['val'];

foreach($array as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

If you would like to access the value as you have done it in your initial PHP snippet you have to modify the `name` attribute of the `input` fileds like this

```
name="val[][val]"
```

But this makes no sense in your case, so you better adjust your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

**While using for each:**

*On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).*

so `$vals` here in your case holds the array element, this variable to get output as :

```
echo $vals;
```